# MediaPlayer stutters after multiple SeekTos

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a `MediaPlayer` playing an mp3 file on which I call `SeekTo()`. It seeks fine. But after a couple of seeks, the player starts jumping back and forth between different times on the audio, *generally* continuing normally. It doesn't give a different `CurrentPosition`, it just stutters.

**More information:**

1. The media is local - a file on the phone.
2. It happens with all files I've tried.
3. Android version: Marshmallow (=6.0)
4. The app is a PCL Xamarin.Forms app running the Droid project. The
   actual playing code is in the Droid part, using
   `Android.Media.MediaPlayer` .
5. I have already tried pausing before the seek, and restarting in the
   `SeekComplete`. Doesn't help.

Comment: To isolate whether this is an issue with Xamarin or Xamarin Forms, it might help to create a Xamarin.Android project (no Xamarin Forms) and see if you get the same behavior, and then also if you feel so bold to do the same with a fully native Java Android app (Use Android Studio) and see if the behavior is the same. Then you can see if it is a Xamarin.Forms issue (does not seem likely), A Xamarin.Android issue (possible), or an issue in Android itself.